# Implementing network (graph) visualization in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, graph, quartz-graphics

I am starting a new project in iPhone SDK in order to represent and manipulate graphs (in the sense of networks, not bar/pie/* charts).

I want to be able to interactively add/move/delete nodes and arcs between them, as well as to pan/zoom the whole representation.

As far as I can see, I have two major options:

- First option: A single view handles it all.
- Second option: Each element (node or arc) has its own associated view.

I think that pros/cons of each option are:

- First option makes the drawing easy (you just populate the data structure and draw the Quartz 2D paths). However detection of touches is problematic, since you have to decide if a given touch point hits a node (this is easy, but you have to poll all nodes) or an edge (this is not so easy).
- Second option makes it easy to implement the detection and handling of touches. However the drawing part could be problematic, since you have to rotate and resize all your views; even worse, if you drag a node you have to tell all the views (holding an edge incident to the given node) to resize/rotate themselves.

Which of the two options would you recommend me?

Thanks in advance,

Biel